# How to use a font in html/css

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am building a website for school, and want to use a special font, but when I import it, it doesn't show the font. I tried using the `@face-font{font-family: something; src: url(font.ttf);` The css I use it on looks like this: `header{font-family: something;}`And I tried this also with a .otf file, but that didn't work either. I also tried `<link ref="font" href="font.ttf">` And also this with a .otf file. But in al cases the font didnt show up. Is it my fault in some code, or is the font just not useable? The link to the font is: http://www.fontspace.com/darrell-flood/quiet-meows

Comment: Check out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/. You'll want to include more than just the TTF or OTF, include all available formats in the @font-face declaration. Also if you can post an example of your CSS that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include the custom font you'll need this somewhere in your CSS:

```
@font-face {
      font-family: 'QuietMeows';
      src: url('../fonts/quiet_meows.ttf')  format('truetype'),
           url('../fonts/quiet_meows.otf')  format('opentype');
}
```

After downloading the font you will need to move it into your project, I put it into a `fonts` folder and renamed to be `quiet_meows`.

Then you can use it in your CSS like this:

```
p {
    font-family: 'QuietMeows';
}
```

Comment: @user9510218 can you provide some code examples of what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Note: If the name of a font family is more than one word, it must be in quotation marks, like: "Times New Roman".

```
   <style> 
@font-face {
   font-family: myFirstFont;
   src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}

@font-face {
   font-family: myFirstFont;
   src: url(sansation_bold.woff);
   font-weight: bold;
}

* {
   font-family: myFirstFont;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The @font-face Rule</h1>

<div>
With CSS, websites can use <b>fonts other than the pre-selected "web-safe" fonts</b>.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier, do not support the @font-face rule.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by adding the format tag. After this, the font did show up on the page. The end looked like this.

```
@font-face{
    font-family: "quiet meows";
    src: url('font.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```